# Textbox or Datepicker in DataTemplate. Based on the data type I want one, but not both

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a datatemplate for my listbox:

```xaml
<DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTextBoxItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" Margin="2,0" Width="140" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FieldData}" Margin="2,0" Width="200" Visibility="{Binding FieldDataVisible}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

However the items in the list that the listbox is bound to are not all String types. Some are DateTime and a few are Integers. I would like to have a datetimepicker displayed instead of a textbox for the DateTime types. How can I make this happen.

To clarify some points the list is populated at runtime using reflection so I don't know which fields are what types ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the Resources block of the ListBox, you could specify a DataTemplate for each type (pseudocode):

```xml
<ListBox.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type String}">
    <TextBlock />
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DateTime}">
    <DateTimePicker />
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

Note that you don't refer to these template by an identifier; they will simply be applied to any instance of the specified DataType in their scope (the ListBox).

Alternatively, you can implement a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to return a different template for each type.

Comment: The objects in the listbox are of type CheckableField and each have the properties IsChecked, DataType, FieldDataVisible and FieldData so I'm not sure the first solution would work. I was thinking of adding two more properties, DateTime and DateTimeVisible. During the population of the list I can set the visible properties to show/hide based on the data type. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: Best bet in that case is to put a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) in the DataTemplate for CheckableField that sets visibility based on DataType. But: you can still use a DataTemplateSelector in this case (use `CheckableField.DataType` to control the selection), or you can put a `DataTrigger` in your ListBox's `ItemContainerStyle` that will set the item's whole template based on the `DataType` property. These give you tighter control over how things are displayed than fiddling with individual properties/visibility.

Comment: Yes... I like the datatrigger in the `ItemContainerStyle`, Thanks.